# Rails Carrierwave if (:medium).present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave

I am currently in the process of trying to move users from version 1 to version 2 of my app. Version 2 is a complete rewrite.

I would like to show the `:medium` version ONLY if it exists. If it doesn't exist then I would like to show `:small`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This is a pretty specific request, so you may want to ask this on the CarrierWave google group: http://groups.google.com/group/carrierwave  ... To be honest, I'm not sure how you'd do this without requesting the file path and checking what the `HEAD` response headers were.

Answer (score 3):

`avatar.medium.file.exists?` is the test you are looking for.

Comment: its too slow process

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question but here is what I would do

as I really like draper, I would create a method in the associated Decorator, but it can also simply be a classic helper method such as

```
def avatar_for(user)
  avatar = user.avatar
  avatar.medium.url || avatar.small.url
end
```

Comment: nope. avatar.medium.url returns what the url WOULD be if it existed, even if it does not exist. need to actual test for existence (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by testing the size not equal to zero

```
if avatar.medium.size == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is:

```
if asset.file.medium.file.exists?
  #show medium version
else
  #show small version
end
```

where file = mounted_uploader and asset = model